# How to determine the gender of a goldfish?

Tags: fish, gender-differentiation, goldfish

How can I determine the sex of a [goldfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldfish)?

The only clues I heard so far were to wait for spawning season, or try to see the shape of the vents, but this get a little trickier if you´re not experienced with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some differences

- The male gold fish usually chase the female ones. If you notice a fish chasing the other, then the fish chasing is probably a male while the fish that is being chased is a female.

The best way is to check during [spawning season](http://www.ask.com/answers/52676661/when-is-spawning-season-for-goldfish),

- The male will develop white spots on their gill covers known as [breeding tubercles](http://www.solidgoldfish.com/2012/09/goldfish-breeding-tubercles.html). Not all male exibit this but most of them do.